# alphavantage: how to get NSE nifty 50 and nifty 100 stock symbols

Tags: stock, alpha-vantage

trying to get historical data of NSE stocks in below intervals:
5Min,1Hour and day.

So how to get Nifty 50 and nifty 100 stock symbols to access data through Alphavantage API.

Comment: In which language are you coding?

Comment: coding in Java language

Answer (score 0):

According to the [alpha vantage docs](https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) you can request plenty of timeseries. Also your desired timeseries are possible (both intraday requests and the daily requests) You find good explanation how you have to set the API Parameter for each time series.
Examples for different languages are also provided below every time series
As for the Nifty Stocks I don't know. Maybe just try the Tickersymbols in the request.